# Por que o PHPUnit não considera retorno antecipado em método no code coverage?

Tags: php, testes, php-7, phpunit

Tenho um código que estou testando com PHPUnit sendo que no método testado há um retorno antecipado com null sob certa condição. Entretanto, o PHPUnit não considera essa parte do código como coberto pelo teste e eu não consigo saber o porquê disto, nem como incluir isso na análise da cobertura de código.

O código em questão é:

```
public function __get(string $name)
    {
        if ($this->hasObservable($name) === false) {
            //Exception
        }
        
        if(key_exists($name, $this->values) === false){
            return null;
        }
        
        return $this->values[$name];
    }
```

O código do teste é o seguinte:

```
public function testMagicGetReturnNull()
    {
        self::$observer->register('test5', 'testingCallbackFunction');
        $this->assertNull(self::$observer->test5);
    }
```

O relatório gerado pelo PHPUnit indica que é a linha com `return null;` que não está coberta:

[image: PHPUnit/Code coverage]

O teste passa, visto que o valor retornado é `null`, porém não sei porque essa parte do código parece não estar sendo coberta.

[O código completo (do commit até o momento desta pergunta) está aqui.](https://github.com/php-tool-kit/observer/commit/94901c37566be32f1c16b94f9e8d792652a306ac)

Comment: Onde você está testando que a chave não existe?

Comment: Na classe tenho uma propriedade ```$value```. Nela através de ```__set()``` eu adiciono o valor ```null``` (com uma chave). No ```__get()``` ele deve testar se determinada chave existe. Se não existir ele retorna ```null```.

Comment: Mas onde testa que dá `null`?

Comment: No teste, na linha ``` $this->assertNull(self::$observer->test5);```.

Comment: Mas o que eu entendi é que ali não dá null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cobertura de código significa testar todas possibilidades, todos os *code paths*, fazer com que todas situações tenham sido simuladas. O ideal é 100%, mas na prática isso é difícil obter, e pode complicar muito. Em geral porcentagens baixas são fáceis, conforme vai subindo vai complicando, quando passa de 90, 95, 98 começa ficar bem complicado, pelo menos na maioria dos casos.

Para dar essa cobertura tem que fazer os caminhos condicionais acontecer. Tem que testar fazendo que entre nos `if`s. Não basta fazer a avaliação da condição, tem que entrar para considerar que cobriu aquela linha.

No caso, pelo menos no que está na pergunta, não há um teste que faça entrar na linha que está em vermelho, a avaliação é feita (a linha verde), mas ela sempre resulta em falso e não entra ali, nunca, portanto está fora da cobertura.

Precisa fazer um teste que faça cair ali. Claro que o teste deve indicar que ali é uma falha, mas o código precisa ser executado no teste. O teste existe para indicar se acontece o que se espera nessa situação. Se o código existe você espera que pode acontecer em alguma situação, mesmo que anormal. Se fosse impossível acontecer o código não deveria existir. Você testa para ver se a situação anormal dá o resultado esperado, mesmo que seja um problema, mas a ação deve ser a certa para uma situação anormal. Sei lá, tente usar a propriedade `teste6`.  Teste tem que tentar tudo o que poderia acontecer de fato na hora que está executando.

E teste não deve testar coisas que são impossíveis de acontecer.

Um erro comum que vejo as pessoas fazerem em testes é que o teste bem feito pode eliminar a possibilidade de erro em produção. Se isso acontecer de fato então não precisa de código para tratar o erro, o que é bom, deixa o código mais rápido, mais limpo. Mas muita gente deixa o tratamento de erro lá no código por via das dúvidas. Ou você confia no teste ou não confia.

Não quer dizer que todo teste pode garantir que algo sempre funcionará, mas alguns podem. Eu gosto especialmente dos testes que evitam códigos de tratamento de erro em tempo de execução.

Esse não parece que pode ser eliminado, então apenas teste que essa parte do código está funcionando corretamente quando usar do jeito errado, porque é isso que ele faz, trata o uso errado. Em outra linguagem esse tratamento não seria necessário e o teste muito menos, por isso que as pessoas falam errado sobre tipagem dinâmica ser mais produtiva, ela é só se você estiver prototipando, fazendo *scripts* simples ou se não quer robustez na sua aplicação.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo. Perfeita resposta. Mostrou o raciocínio que eu não estava fazendo. No caso o código retornaria ```null``` em duas ocasiões: se a chave não estivesse definida ou se não houvesse a definição de valor, já que todas as chaves tem por valor padrão ```null```. Além disso, aprendi mais uma coisa: se confiamos nos testes, não precisamos de tratamento de erros. Sempre aprendendo com o @Maniero. Obrigado pela lição.